# Custom setter method won't accept blank values in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this class:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :hourly_rate

  validates :hourly_rate, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }, 
                          :allow_blank => true, 
                          :allow_nil => true

  def hourly_rate
    read_attribute(:hourly_rate_in_cents) / 100
  end

  def hourly_rate=(number)
    write_attribute(:hourly_rate_in_cents, number.to_d * 100)
  end

end
```

The problem is that my setter method doesn't behave in the way I want it.

In my form, when I leave the `hourly_rate` input field blank and then hit `Update`, a `0` appears in the input field again as if by magic and I get a validation error: `Hourly rate must be greater than 0`

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here? I want that field to be optional.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you share the view code ?? model is not giving enough clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the problem is that if you leave the field blank, `params[:project][:hourly_rate]` will be `""`. If you do `@project.hourly_rate = ""` then `@project.hourly_rate` will be `0`, not nil.

This is because `"".to_d` is `0`. Therefore `write_attribute(:hourly_rate_in_cents, number.to_d * 100)` will write the value `0` when `number` is `""`.

```
def hourly_rate=(number)
  hourly_rate_value = number.present? ? number.to_d * 100 : nil
  write_attribute(:hourly_rate_in_cents, hourly_rate_value)
end
```

should fix this.

Comment: Hm strange. When I add that line, and then try to save a blank `hourly_rate` field, the previous value gets shown, e.g. "50". I must be missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: I didn't understand your use case properly, have updated my answer.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot! The description you're giving really nails it even though as a Rails n00b I had to read through it a couple of times. I just wonder why I've never come across a code snippet like this before... The use case is pretty simple actually: Get a decimal from the user and then save it to the DB as an integer. Apparently this is quite common when dealing with money values to avoid floating point errors.

Comment: Just a shame that I have a whole bunch of setter methods like the one above. I don't really fancy adding that line of code to all of those. Isn't there a shortcut or something?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this condition in your model:

```
validates :hourly_rate, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }.
```

You're telling it to be greater than 0.
Either provide input > 0 or comment out that line with "#" in front of it.

When you first did the migration, it put those conditions in so now undo that as follows.

```
rails g migration remove_numericality_from_hourly_rate
```

Then in your migration file:

```
class RemoveNumericallityFromHourlyRate < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up

 change_column :my_table, :hourly_rate, :string 
 end   
end
```

Then run this: 
run rake db:migrate

Comment: No, it's definitely not that line causing the trouble. I just commented it out and nothing changed. The problem must be my getter and setter methods.

Comment: when you comment it out, you will have to reload your app. I think that's your problem. Lets confirm it: do this: rake db:schema:dump, then post the result of followring: cat db/schema.rb